# Extract values from a list based on a condition

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to get a sample from a list based on a condition. It should be easy to do but I am unable to do it as following:

```
a = [2,4,5,9,1,6,4]
b = 6
c = [x for x in a if a < b]
```

I basically need a new list which should contain values less than 6. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or, the other way:

```
>>> a = [2,4,5,9,1,6,4]
>>> b = 6
>>> c = filter(lambda x: x < b, a)
>>> c
[2, 4, 5, 1, 4]
```

You almost had it as Ignacio pointed out:

```
>>> c = [x for x in a if x < b]
>>> c
[2, 4, 5, 1, 4]
```

The list comprehension is a longer way of writing this loop:

```
>>> c = []
>>> for x in a:
...     if x < b:
...         c.append(x)
...
>>> c
[2, 4, 5, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed. You need to compare each element, not the sequence.

```
c = [x for x in a if x < b]
```

Comment: OP also compares `str` with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you meant `if x < b`, right?
You also have a problem there that the values in array a are strings and not ints.
so:
`[x for x in a if int(x)<b]`

Comment: `int(x)`? `x` will always be an integer.